# Symfony simple authentication system

Tags: symfony

I have a project that use FOS User Bundle. It works fine.
FOS User Bundle manage Customer authentication/

But i want to give an access to suppliers to a single page.
I do not want to create user accounts for suppliers because they need to access to a unique webpage.

I am looking for the simplest way to authenticate my suppliers in my web application. The suppliers table already contains some fields that can be use as login and password. Passwords are not encrypted but it does not matter.

So my question is, what is the simplest way to show an http authentication popup when i wall the page, check if the supplier exists in the database, and display static information ?

I do not want to work with FOSUserBundle and stuff. I want the simplest way.

Comment: It seems you need custom user provider. and, likely, separate firewall

Comment: no way to do something simplest ?

Comment: Do you mean i will need to add records in fos_user table for my suppliers ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly "**The suppliers table already contains some fields that can be use as login and password.**" means that you already have some table for suppliers. So, why not use it?

Comment: I want to use this table but when we work with firewall, customer user provider, that s mean we must use FOSUserBundle or something like that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96240/discussion-between-sergio-ivanuzzo-and-testpresta).